# Cocoa Error 2048 on NSRegularExpression

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm attempting to use NSRegularExpression to search for a string inside a pbxproj (Inside the .xcodeproj folder).

I'm searching for the compiler flags in the "Begin PBXBuildFile section" area

```
NSString* findFlagsRegex = @"([A-Z0-9]{24}\\s\\/\\*\\s[A-Za-z\\.\\s0-9]+\\*\\/\\s=\\s{isa\\s\\=\\s[A-Za-z]*;\\s?fileRef\\s\\=\\s[A-Z0-9]*\\s\\/\\*\\s[A-Za-z0-9\\s\\.]*\\*\\/;\\ssettings\\s\\=\\s{[A-Za-z0-9_\\s\\=\"-]*;\\s\\};\\s};)";
NSRegularExpression* expression3 = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:findFlagsRegex options:kNilOptions error:&err];
NSLog(@"Error: %@",[err description]);

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The value “([A-Z0-9]{24}\s\/\*\s[A-Za-z\.\s0-9]+\*\/\s=\s{isa\s\=\s[A-Za-z]*;\s?fileRef\s\=\s[A-Z0-9]*\s\/\*\s[A-Za-z0-9\s\.]*\*\/;\ssettings\s\=\s{[A-Za-z0-9_\s\="-]*;\s\};\s};)” is invalid." UserInfo=0x61800026a7c0 {NSInvalidValue=([A-Z0-9]{24}\s\/\*\s[A-Za-z\.\s0-9]+\*\/\s=\s{isa\s\=\s[A-Za-z]*;\s?fileRef\s\=\s[A-Z0-9]*\s\/\*\s[A-Za-z0-9\s\.]*\*\/;\ssettings\s\=\s{[A-Za-z0-9_\s\="-]*;\s\};\s};)}
```

I copy:

```
  ([A-Z0-9]{24}\s\/\*\s[A-Za-z\.\s0-9]+\*\/\s=\s{isa\s\=\s[A-Za-z]*;\s?fileRef\s\=\s[A-Z0-9]*\s\/\*\s[A-Za-z0-9\s\.]*\*\/;\ssettings\s\=\s{[A-Za-z0-9_\s\="-]*;\s\};\s};)
```

The regular expression above works in RegexPal, directly copying it from the invalid value from the error message on the same test data... so I'm not sure what's wrong :/

Not sure if this will add anything, but this is a Mac App and not an iOS app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern contains a lone literal `}`. I believe you meant to have two literal `{`s and two literal `}`s - this is a slightly modified version of the pattern you had in your question, with three more `\\`s inserted to escape the curly braces that are currently not escaped in your code.

```
NSString* findFlagsRegex = @"([A-Z0-9]{24}\\s\\/\\*\\s[A-Za-z\\.\\s0-9]+\\*\\/\\s=\\s\\{isa\\s\\=\\s[A-Za-z]*;\\s?fileRef\\s\\=\\s[A-Z0-9]*\\s\\/\\*\\s[A-Za-z0-9\\s\\.]*\\*\\/;\\ssettings\\s\\=\\s\\{[A-Za-z0-9_\\s\\=\"-]*;\\s\\};\\s\\};)";
```

I'm not sure whether the bug is with RegexPal, or if RegexPal depends on the copy of JS that your browser uses, or if the bug is with `NSRegularExpression`s, but either way, escaping a character which doesn't need to be escaped shouldn't cause any issues (or at least it's not my understanding of regular expressions that it should.)

Comment: Thanks... this was driving me crazy!